# How to append a Matrix to a Vector in Julia

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, julia

During my implementation of ML using [Julia](https://julialang.org/), I want to create an empty Array that takes matrices of W's, so all the W's are used in on notation and an index

Like for layer 1 on `W[1]`, for layer 2 `W[2]` where W is of the following type `Vector{Matrix{Float64}}`

I tried the following

```
julia> W = Vector{Matrix{Float64}}()
0-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}

julia> append!(W, randn(2,3))
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Float64 to an object of type Array{Float64,2}
Closest candidates are:
  convert(::Type{T}, ::AbstractArray) where T<:Array at array.jl:490
  convert(::Type{T}, ::T) where T<:AbstractArray at abstractarray.jl:14
  convert(::Type{T}, ::LinearAlgebra.Factorization) where T<:AbstractArray at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/LinearAlgebra/src/factorization.jl:53
```

Even if I tried `push!` it returned something weired

```
julia> push!(W, randn(2,3))
7-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}:
 #undef                                                                                                                         
 #undef                                                                                                                         
 #undef                                                                                                                         
 #undef                                                                                                                         
 #undef                                                                                                                         
 #undef                                                                                                                         
    [1.0062340094124418 -0.38626851094866743 -0.33618129619245823; 0.015522767526406687 0.28674191528121296 -1.0633951718710888]
```

Comment: There must be something wrong here. `push!` works just fine with your example. Have you intialized `W` as `Vector{Matrix{Float64}}(undef, 7)` in the meantime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to simply use `push!`

```
julia> W = Vector{Matrix{Float64}}()
0-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}

julia> push!(W, randn(2,3));

julia> push!(W, randn(2,3))
2-element Array{Array{Float64,2},1}:
 [0.3576168242438958 -1.317283838543733 1.2032446558953898; -0.23459653777447262 -1.0726558200371563 0.41327008176749974]
 [-0.09498247388794684 1.1652097582191079 0.33822625635995557; -0.12996397909088794 -1.1759095197792893 0.2507353185439138]
```

Now you are wondering "where to hell those `#undef` values came from?".
When you were trying to use `append!` it actually managed to extend the size of your `W` by six elements (try running `length(randn(2,3))` to see yourself). This happens because `append!` iterates over a list and of course it is possible to iterate over a matrix. So you could observe a side effect of your error.

Last, but not least. If your arrays are small (and this could be your case) consider using `StaticArrrays` which are much faster for stable array size on CPU (unless you do GPU).

Answer (score 6):

The real solution is to use `push!` instead of `append!`.
If you go to help in the REPL (pressing `?`), you can see the docs for `push!`:

```
help?> push!
search: push! pushfirst! pushdisplay

  push!(collection, items...) -> collection

  Insert one or more items at the end of collection.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> push!([1, 2, 3], 4, 5, 6)
  6-element Array{Int64,1}:
   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6

  Use append! to add all the elements of another collection to collection. The result of the preceding example is
  equivalent to append!([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]).
```